# Import Error: No module named django - for specific project

Tags: django, python-2.7, ubuntu, python-import

I have installed Django(1.8.2) in my Ubuntu 16.04.
When I cloned a working project into it and run the server, I got the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "manage.py", line 31, in <module>
      execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338,  in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/django/apps/config.py", line 119, in create
    import_module(entry)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
  __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named django
```

**Observation(s):**

- I'm able to start a new project and run the server of the same.
- The value of `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` is:

  ```
  INSTALLED_APPS = (
     'django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'Telecommands',
     'Telemetry',
     'captcha',
     'django.contrib.sitemaps',
     'djcelery',
     'kombu.transport.django',
     # 'grappelli',
     # 'chronograph',
     # 'registration', # Include the registration
  )
  ```

**What have I tried?**

- Installing django using `pip install django==1.8.2`.
- Since the error was reported with reference to `/usr/lib/python2.7/`,
  I tried:
  `sudo pip install --install-option="--install-purelib=/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/" --ignore-installed django==1.8.2`
- Further, when I got confused with paths
  `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`,
  `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`
  and `~/.local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`.
  I installed django(1.8.2) to each of these paths one by one,
  updating `PYTHONPATH` in parallel.
- I did **not** get any errors while installing.

Can somebody help me out. Kindly explain the reason for the error as well.

Comment: Question is updated with `INSTALLED_APPS` vaule.

Comment: The latest Django 1.8.x release is currently 1.8.16. If you are running 1.8.2, then you are missing several security fixes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The traceback shows you the error occurs in `/usr/lib/python2.7/django/__init__.py`, so `manage.py` has clearly found your Django installation. As an aside, it would be much better to use a virtual env instead of installing in `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`.

The problem appears to be that you have `kombu.transport.django` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`. The [Django transport was removed from kombu in 4.0](http://docs.celeryproject.org/projects/kombu/en/master/changelog.html#version-4-0).

Comment: Your fix worked. It was working fine with my team mates laptop.
 with same configurations. (Installed long back). :)

Comment: If it works on your team mate's laptop, they probably have kombu < 4.0 installed.

Comment: Could you please explain how this cause a problem. I'm bit amazed that an error in module somehow 'mask' another.

Comment: You get the error because you have `kombu.transport.django` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`, but it does not exist. Similarly if you had `kombu.transport.foobar` in `INSTALLED_APPS`, then you would get the error `ImportError: No module named foobar`. In that case, it would be clearer what the problem is, because the name doesn't clash.